# Modify matrix based on column values

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix

```
a = [[1,2,-3,1],
     [-1,0,0,1], 
     [1,1,1,1]]
```

i want to modify it such that the result will contain only the columns that are positive.

```
a =  [[2, 1], 
      [0, 1], 
      [1, 1]]

def removing_missing_data(x):

    """
    input: lists of lists.
    return: non-negative values.
    """
    for i in x:
        f = []
        for k in i:
            if k < 0:
                f.append(i.index(k))
        t(f,x)

def t(x,y):
    count = 0
    for i in x:
        i = i - count
        for l in y:
            l.pop(i)
        count+=1
```

The code above works but its not efficient way to deal when the matrix is too large. I would like to know if there is any way to deal with this issue to optimize the running time so it can be used on large data sets.

Comment: If you are dealing with matrices and need performance: numpy is the way to go

Comment: >>> a = np.array([[1,2,-3,1],[-1,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1]])
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2, -3,  1],
       [-1,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1]])
>>> a>0
array([[ True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> a[a>0]
array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> np.transpose(a[a>0])
array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> np.extract(a>0,a)
array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the min item in each column and then filter the positive ones. It can be done very easy with numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[1,2,-3,1],
...      [-1,0,0,1],
...      [1,1,1,1]]
>>> b = np.array(a)
>>> b[:,(b.min(axis=0)>=0)]
array([[2, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```